# How to remove object from an array which have a key value as undefined in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a list which after selecting values returns an array. Now, suppose I select 1st and 3rd values skipping 2nd one then the array returned is as :

```
 [
  {
   "cname": "10TKN", 
   "code": "403", 
   "id": 1
  },
  {
   "cname": undefined, 
   "code": undefined, 
   "id": 2
  }, 
  {
   "cname": "20TKN", 
   "code": "403", 
   "id": 3
  }
 ]
```

I want the expected result as :

```
 [
   {
    "cname": "10TKN", 
    "code": "403", 
    "id": 1
   },
   {
    "cname": "20TKN", 
    "code": "403", 
    "id": 3
   }
 ]
```

Comment: @jianshu does that help?

Comment: can you be more accurate? , you want to get those with `cname` and `code` properties which are not `undefined`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's `Array.filter()` to filter away `undefined` values.

```js
const data = [
  {
   "cname": "10TKN", 
   "code": "403", 
   "id": 1
  },
  {
   "cname": undefined, 
   "code": undefined, 
   "id": 2
  }, 
  {
   "cname": "20TKN", 
   "code": "403", 
   "id": 3
  }
 ];
 
 const res = data.filter(({cname, code, id }) => cname && code && id);
 console.log(res);
```

This will ensure that only objects with truthy values are returned.

Alternatively, as mentioned by HMR on the comments, if you only want to check for `undefined`, it will be better to do this:

```
const res = data.filter(({cname, code, id }) => cname !== undefined && code !== undefined && id !== undefined);
```

Comment: Could have unpredictable edge case when using falsy, if OP wants to remove when prop is undefined then best check for that: `cname !== undefined && code !== undefined`

Comment: @HMR yeah agree. It really depends on the OP's requirements. He might want to keep the `null`s or `0`s. If that is the case, it will be better to do an `undefined` check like what you have suggested!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the key that we want to evaluate is `cname`.
We need to filter out the array using `Array.filter` function -:

```js
let arr = [
  {
   "cname": "10TKN", 
   "code": "403", 
   "id": 1
  },
  {
   "cname": undefined, 
   "code": undefined, 
   "id": 2
  }, 
  {
   "cname": "20TKN", 
   "code": "403", 
   "id": 3
  }
 ];

arr = arr.filter(({cname}) => cname);
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` as suggested already but you will have to check for the selected id(s) from list and then discard the ones not selected. In short you will return true only if the list object id matches with the one you selected

```js
const dataList = [
  {
   "cname": "10TKN", 
   "code": "403", 
   "id": 1
  },
  {
   "cname": undefined, 
   "code": undefined, 
   "id": 2
  }, 
  {
   "cname": "20TKN", 
   "code": "403", 
   "id": 3
  }
 ];

 const selectedDataIds = [1, 3];
 const res = dataList.filter(({ id }) => selectedDataIds.includes(id));
 console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Destructuring assignment` and skip some values with a comma,
like this:

```js
const arr = [
  {
   "cname": "10TKN", 
   "code": "403", 
   "id": 1
  },
  {
   "cname": undefined, 
   "code": undefined, 
   "id": 2
  }, 
  {
   "cname": "20TKN", 
   "code": "403", 
   "id": 3
  }
 ]
 
const [first, ,third] = arr;

console.log(first, third);
```

[Destructuring assignment - Ignoring some returned values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Ignoring_some_returned_values)